# How to correct set up rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this setting for my website for SEO-friendly URL, it's working correct. But when I need set some **301 Redirect** it works poorly. When I type in address bar that rule below `Redirect 301  /example1 /example2` I get `www.domain.com/example2?page=example1`. How can I change it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirect 301  /example1 /example2
```

Comment: Do you want to sent example2 to index.php at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep using mod_rewrite since you're already using it. And put the rule above the other one.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^example/? /example2 [L,R=301]

#redirect to index.php except for example2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example2
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```